# How do I denote a linear regression with AR - correlation?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, autoregressive

We can fit linear models and add correlation coeffitients. In the example, x is the dependent variable, which was measured during a time series:

```
library (nlme) 
gls (x ~ time, 
           data = my_data, 
           correlation = corAR1 (form = ~ time))
```

My very simple question is: how is this sort of regression called? Is this a "linear autoregressive model"? Or is there a better name?

Comment: Following the example of Zuur et al. (ISBN 978-0-387-87457-9) I'd call it a linear model with residual auto-correlation structure.

Comment: All those models are under 'Generalized Linear Models'